# Flutter dart:io problem with reading and writing file

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-io

I'm trying to read data from TXT file but somthing goes wrong. There is a code

```
import 'dart:async'
import 'dart:io';
void main(){
File('file.txt').readAsString().then((String contents){
 print(contents);
});
}
```

This is code From official documentation.also I tried change path to my file in File('') like (assets/file.txt) but stil nothing work. I getting this error after starting program

```
Error: Unsupported operation: _Namespace
```

I know that i need to add assets at pbuspec.yaml file, i did it.
also when i using rootBundle from services.dart, to read this file.txt, everything is working fine and i can read data from it.

Comment: Are trying to run this for Flutter Web? If so, that is your problem. The `dart:io` package does not work on web

Comment: I think the problem is you need to provide complete path. You can't use `File` class for files bundled into your app. File class works with actual files on mobile (like you apk file). Try path_provider plugin to find `getTemporaryDirectory` or something.

Answer (score 0):

The `Dart` code shown above has a syntax error - the first line does not have a `;`. When I run it I get this error:

```
$ dart run file.dart
file.dart:1:8: Error: Expected ';' after this.
import 'dart:async'
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that you do not need to import this library. If I remove this line then it successfully reads the file `file.txt` in the current directory.

You mention using `rootBundle` to read an asset file - this is all appropriate to `Flutter`, as opposed to the simple `Dart` program that you show.

As mentioned in the comments to your question, `dart:io` cannot be used for Flutter Web apps, because the browser does not permit file access. It can be used for Flutter Mobile and Desktop apps. See [Reading and Writing Files](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files).